# Nextjs API works in local environment but not in production environment

Tags: reactjs, next.js, fetch, vercel

**[SOLVED]**

I have created a `dynamic` API route in NextJS that, if given a `filename`, the server will read the file (`.md` or `.txt` file) under the `content` directory, convert it into string and returns it. The API works as intended in `local` environment, however, the deployed website in `Vercel` doesn't work properly for this API route.

That API route, for a file that exists in the `content` directory, returns `500 internal server error`.

The console error is:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 ()
```

Checking the vercel logs for the route, showed this:

```
ERROR Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'content/phase1_section1.md'
```

I think the `path.join()` is not working for me. It is not adding the actual domain name of the app in front of the content part. How can I resolve this?

And, here's the `code`

```
import { readFileSync } from 'fs';
import path from "path";

export default function courseHandler({ query: { slug } }, res) {
    const fullPath = path.join('./content/', slug);
    const content = readFileSync(fullPath, 'utf8');
    if (content) {
        res.status(200).json({
            content: content
        });
    } else {
        res.status(404).json({ message: `Course with slug: ${slug} not found.` })
    }
}
```

Comment: A 500 error can be anything. Can you check out the logs in Vercel?

Comment: Yes, just checked. I think the path is not working for me. 
ERROR Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'content/phase1_section1.md'

It is not adding the actual domain name of the app in front of the content part.

How can I resolve this?

Comment: Can you locate `content/phase1_section1.md` on the environment where your API is running?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I solved the issue. The issue was with file path.

Comment: Faced Same problem and find [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73233293/next-js-bad-request-when-trying-any-request-in-production/74128966#74128966)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is actually solved.

I just replaced this

```
path.join('./content/', slug);
```

with this

```
path.join(process.cwd(), 'content', slug);
```

Answer (score 3):

1. Check logs on Vercel
2. Configure yours [.env variables](https://vercel.com/docs/concepts/projects/environment-variables) on Vercel for each environment
3. Check your local `.env` files. if you hardcoded your .env variables - this will cause a negative impact.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I set the variables right. But the issue was with file path.