# NEXT JS Bad request when trying any request in production

Tags: javascript, next.js, request

I've build a project with NEXT js and now got a problem. When I run my project in development and make a request from the client to an enpoint e.g:

```
fetch("/api/game")
        .then((res) => res.json())
        .then((data) => setGames(data.games));
```

everything works as expected and I get my data.

Now I build my project with `npx next build` and run it with `npx next start` and my pages still work as expected, yet every request to an api route results in `400 Bad Request` error. The requests do not reach the handler function of my api endpoints, that I set up and just return this error.

If you need any more info please tell me and I will give you further inside.

I looked through some other question posted online, but couldn't find any help to solve that problem.

Thanks you for any help in advance.
Linus

Comment: Well, what does the response content contain?

Comment: So the content is just a html document displaying 400 Bad request. Here are the headers from the response: [headers](https://pastebin.com/Xq9YvJv2)

Comment: Can you show us the code for the API route?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just make sure that the url from which the request is being sent is using HTTPS and not HTTP. I was facing the same issue and changing it from HTTP to HTTPS worked for me!